# Integrating bitbucket with cloudbees

Tags: bitbucket, cloudbees

I am new to bitbucket and cloudbees. Is anyone aware of the ways to connect them. Any detailed documentation about integrating them with complete details of output. Please help I am stuck with this for 3 days. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just released [bitbucket jenkins plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Plugin) to address this use-case, as bitbucket "jenkins" hook is really poor and offer minimal service. Let me know your account ID if you want me to install it, and configure a "POST" hook on your repo with URL https://.ci.cloudbees.com/bitbucket-hook (no need for credentials)

I also updated http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Bitbucket to reflect this new option.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I somehow managed to get the contents from bitbucket repository to Jenkin build manually by using SSH key and git URL. It does not happen on commit to bitbucket though.

Comment: I will try to use bitbucket plugin as mentioned in new documentation.